# add multiple json field by python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file like:

```
{
  "parentNode": {
    "id": "root",
    "mbs": [
      16995.9859862176,
      -6029.919928079834,
      -4.6344976928710935,
      4674.872691701428
    ]
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "00t2",
      "mbs": [
        16561.761031809023,
        -5189.992543469676,
        5,
        221.7414398051216
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "01t2",
      "mbs": [
        16851.244334748077,
        -5189.992543469676,
        5,
        221.7414398051216
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to change the mbs value but to take a log before for roll back.

so my code is like:

```py
if jsondict['parentNode']:
    mbsx=jsondict['parentNode']['mbs'][0]
    mbsy=jsondict['parentNode']['mbs'][1]
    nodeid=jsondict['parentNode']['id']  #log the node id and mbs value

    jsondict['mymbs_parent']=[nodeid,mbsx,mbsy]  #write em down

    jsondict['parentNode']['mbs'][0]=mbsx+xoffset  #then change the value
    jsondict['parentNode']['mbs'][1]=mbsy+yoffset
```

That works fine for parent node,

but there maybe many children nodes, so for the children part, the code is like this:

```py
if jsondict['children']:
    count=len(jsondict['children'])
    for i in range(count):
        mbsx=jsondict['children'][i]['mbs'][0]
        mbsy=jsondict['children'][i]['mbs'][1]
        nodeid=jsondict['children'][i]['id']
        jsondict['mymbs_children'][i]=(nodeid,mbsx,mbsy)
        jsondict['children'][i]['mbs'][0]=mbsx+xoffset
        jsondict['children'][i]['mbs'][1]=mbsy+yoffset
```

then I get `list assignment index out of range` error.

I guess there isn't `mymbs_children` in the json file yet so there isn't `jsondict['mymbs_children'][i]`

I haven't found out how to do it, any ideas?

Comment: FYI, the code works fine if I remove the [i] but then it only writes down the last children's node value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't love your approach, but for simplicity I can answer the question you have asked. To fix the error you are getting, add

```
    jsondict['mymbs_children'] = []
```

as the first line in the block after

```
if jsondict['children']:
```

This will create the list which you are then trying to write to.

Then you need to use `.append()` to add the items to the list:

```
jsondict['mymbs_children'].append((nodeid,mbsx,mbsy))
```

instead of

```
jsondict['mymbs_children'][i]=(nodeid,mbsx,mbsy)
```

Comment: Ah of course, you're trying to assign directly to a list item. You'll need to either use `.append()` instead, or initialise the list first. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can put an `if` condition surrounding the `for` loop to check:

```
  ...
  if count > 0:
    for i in range(count):
      ...
```

for python 3.8 onwards, you can use walrus operator as well to cut down the number of lines of code: ([for more info](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#syntax-and-semantics))

```
  ...
  if (count := len(jsondict['children'])) > 0:
    for i in range(count):
      ...
```

another way which I prefer is to not use `range`:

```
...
    for child in jsondict['children']:
      child['mbs'][blah]...
...
```

this will avoid the issue of *out of range index*, and you might not even need to use the `count` variable

Comment: I didn'y know ``` for child in jsondict['children']``` directly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
# Key "mymbs_children" is not present in the dictionary yet,
# so you'll need to declare it first and initialise to an empty list.
jsondict['mymbs_children'] = []
if jsondict['children']:
    count=len(jsondict['children'])
    for i in range(count):
        mbsx=jsondict['children'][i]['mbs'][0]
        mbsy=jsondict['children'][i]['mbs'][1]
        nodeid=jsondict['children'][i]['id']
        # Use append to add the tuple to this list
        jsondict['mymbs_children'].append((nodeid,mbsx,mbsy));
```